# How to estimate magnitude of expontent?

Tags: exponentiation, estimation, mental-arithmetic

When given an exponent, such as 6^12, is there a simple way to approximate how large(magnitude) the result is, without performing the calculation? Is this method accurate for large exponents?

Comment: One way is to learn the common logarithms of the integers 2 through 9 to one or two decimal places.  So $ \ \log_{10} 6 \ \approx \ 0.8 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \log_{10} 6^{12} \ \approx \ 9.6 \ . $ Since  $ \ \log_{10} 4 \ \approx \ 0.6 \   \  $ , we can estimate $ \ 6^{12} \ \sim \  4 \ \cdot \ 10^9 \ $ (which turns out to be somewhat high -- by about a factor of 2).  Another way might be to use $ \ 6^3 \ = \ 216 \ \approx \ 200 \ $ , so $ \ 6^{12} \ \approx \ 200^4 \ = \ 2^4 \ \cdot \ 10^8 \ = \ 1.6 \ \cdot \ 10^9 \ $ (a little low).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner:   that should be an answer.

Comment: Estimation is made much easier as you have more facts available without thinking about them.  $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.3 \implies 2^{10} \approx 1000$ is amazingly useful.  That plus $(1+x)^n \approx 1+nx$ for $x\ll1$ can get you a long ways.  More facts and more Taylor series make it easier.  Like so many other skills, if you want to do this well, you need to practice.

Comment: As an example, what is the volume of the earth?  The radius is 4000 miles or 6400 km, which is $2^6\cdot 10^2$ km.  The volume is $\frac 43\pi r^3$ and (since $\pi=3$ for this purpose) $V=4(2^6 \cdot 10^2)^3=2^{20}10^6=10^{12}$km$^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing estimation, you need to be conscious of the allowable errors.  Knowing some logs helps, too. If you know that $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.3$ and $3^2\approx 10$ you are done. $\log_{10}6^{12}=\log_{10}(2^{12})+\log_{10}(3^{12})\approx 12 \cdot 0.3+6=9.6,$ so $6^{12}\approx 4\cdot 10^9$  Douglas Hofstadter claimed that this is the region we care mostly about how many zeros there are.  Of course, you can get the [exact result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E12) $2176782336$, which is a factor $2$ below my approximation-mostly because $3^2=9$, not $10$, but I claim a factor $2$ here is acceptable.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Estimation is an under-taught, under-utilized skill in the age of cheap calculators.  But it is quite often valuable for making basic judgements where an order of magnitude (or half-order) is adequate for a decision, or for doing simple "sanity-checks" of all manner of calculations.  I tell students they should learn ways to estimate answers first, and use calculators or computers only when "precision" work is needed.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to learn the common logarithms of the integers 2 through 9 to one or two decimal places. So  $ \ \log_{10} 6 \ ≈ \ 0.8 \  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \log_{10}  \ 6^{12} \ ≈ \ 9.6 \ $ . Since  $ \ \log_{10} 4 \ ≈ \ 0.6 \ $   , we can estimate $ \  6^{12} \ ∼ \ 4 ⋅ 10^9 \ $ (which turns out to be somewhat high -- by about a factor of 2).

Another way might be to use $ \ 6^3 \ = \ 216 \ ≈ \ 200 \ $ , so  $ \ 6^{12} \ ≈ \ 200^4 \ = \ 2^4 ⋅ 10^8 \ = \ 1.6 ⋅ 10^9 \ $ (a little low).  If you work with numbers much, you will find it helpful to learn (actually, you start to involuntarily *memorize*) the low integer powers of the low integers.  (Over the years, I've ended up with "times-tables" out past 20 x 20 , and powers of the integers of at least 2 through 20 up to cubes or more...)